# RxJava operator that emits if different from last

Tags: rx-java

Is there an operator that emits items if the item to be emitted is not equal the last emitted item?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is [`distinctUntilChanged()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/distinct.html).

> RxJava also implements the distinctUntilChanged operator. It only compares emitted items from the source Observable against their immediate predecessors in order to determine whether or not they are distinct.

[image: distinctUntilChanged marble diagram]

Comment: That close but not quite. This operator wont emit an item that was emitted before. I want an operator that just compares with the last emitted item, not all the previous

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's exactly what `distinctUntilChanged()` does.

Comment: but the marble diagram does not say so. according to the example in the marble diagram i would like the output to be: 1,2,1,3. instead of 1,2,3

Comment: you are looking at diagram for `distinct()` not `distinctUntilChanged()`