# How to emit a boolean only when the previous one is different using Rx Operator?

Tags: rx-java2, reactivex

I have a boolean Observable. I want to emit value(another boolean) only if the current boolean value is different from preview.

```
booleanObservable

            // which operator here

            .subscribe(new Consumer<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Boolean emittedBoolean) throws Exception {
                    // do something with emittedBoolean
                }
            });
```

Comment: `Observable.distinctUntilChanged`

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638941/rxjava-operator-that-emits-if-different-from-last) question.

Comment: @DeanXu worked! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use this : [distinctUntilChanged()](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/distinct.html)